# Using Python_stubs with vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to use VS-Code for my python code. But there is a problem with the extensions (or include path) but I don't know how to fix this.

For example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

os.getcwd();
os.listdir();
```

If i want to know where getcwd or listdir is declared and what the description of this function is, then I always end in this folder:
[image]

Then I end up in the extensions folder and there is no description. Actually I don't know that this should be. This is an example of the "declaration" in this file:

```
def getcwd() -> str: ...
def getcwdb() -> bytes: ...
def chmod(path: FileDescriptorOrPath, mode: int, *, dir_fd: int | None = None, 
follow_symlinks: bool = True) -> None: ...
```

I am using Pycharm to execute the Program. But I like to code in vs-code.

If I am searching for the declaration in Pycharm I end up in this directory:

AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.2\python_stubs-61526171

Does somebody know how to fix the Interpration of my search?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Most of the `os` module is implemented in a C library, not in Python code.  Python doesn't use "declarations", so there is no file where you can find those strings.

Comment: @Tim The closest thing to a function declaration is a type annotation, which is given by a stub in this case, so that's what the IDEs are showing. (BTW, Python does have declarations, `global` and `nonlocal`, but that's beside the point.) That said, I agree, I'm not following the question. I guess by "description" they mean "docstring", which is normally given by the Hover / Suggestion Details / Parameter Hints, and those work for me for `listdir` but not `getcwd`, though I'm using Jedi not Pylance.